# TFS re-add Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I have a project that is source controlled using TFS. I was doing some coding on my laptop when, unfortunately, my computer crashed and I ended up having to re-install Windows. I was afraid that all my code would be lost, but thankfully I was able to restore the code files.

My problem is that now I need to commit the changes to TFS.  Currently the projects do not have any source bindings.  I can't overwrite the current code base because there is work that has been done since my crash by other devs.

How can I add the changes I've made to TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i've done something like this is kinda hackish, but what i usually do is get latest from TFS onto my laptop, and checkout all of the code from the project in question.  Then i take the changed code and copy it over that folder, check it in.  TFS should be smart enough to only really affect the actual code items that have been changed.  You can see in the history the actual files that got changed to be sure.

If you know the exact files that you need to update, then that will make things much easier, because you can do the above steps, but then just check out the particular files you know of.  You can do a compare between them and your new code to make sure that you don't overwrite anything your other programmers have done.  Again, hackish, but i don't know of any streamlined way to do this.

You might want to make sure that you download the TFS visual studio extension, since that will give you rollback capability.

Comment: Nice! +1 for hackish :) I'll check it out and see if it works in my case

Comment: It would be easiest if you use Get Specific Version and try to find the version you had in your original windows installation, that way it will be easier to merge any files. Be weary of any added or removed files, these changes are not automatically picked up by pasting the modified sources.

Comment: You could also use the Compare Folders feature in the Source Control Explorer to compare the server version to your local version and then merge the files that have any changes.

Comment: Yeah, the Compare Folders feature would have worked well.  I did the copy and replace and it all synced up (after a little bit of massaging).  Phew!  back to being productive!